# Strange behaviour with multiple Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got some strange behaviour with a javascript file, when I have multiple functions in the .js file.

I have a Logging.js file, which writes to a text file:

```
function WriteLog(message)
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var textFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users\\sysadmin\\Desktop\\Tom's Work Area\\file.txt", 8, true);

    textFile.WriteLine(message);
    textFile.Close();
}
```

And I call this function in my HTML like so:

```
<head>
     <script src="C:\\Users\\sysadmin\\Desktop\\Tom's Work Area\\Logging.js" type="text/Javascript" </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        WriteLog("text");
    </script>
</body>
```

Which works perfectly, however, when I add another function to my Logging.js file:

```
function getDate()
{
    try{
    var date = new Date();

    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var day = date.getDate();
    if (day < 10)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    var hour = date.getHours();

    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if (minutes <= 9)
    {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if (seconds <= 9)
    {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    var dateString = "" + day "/" + month + "/year" + " " + hours + ":" + minutes ":" + seconds;

    return dateString;
    }

    catch(e)
    {
        Script.writeln(e.description);
    }
}
```

Then the writing to a text file doesn't even work, as if the Logging.js file doesn't work anymore! Even when I don't call the getDate() function.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Use the developer console

Comment: Keep your browser developer console open. You would have seen the error there, and the error did in fact make the whole JavaScript file not work.

Comment: Only a note: this is the third post that i've seen this afternoon with the same code. `<script src="C:\\Users\\sysadmin\\Desktop\\Tom's Work Area\\Logging.js" type="text/Javascript" </script>` this makes me laugh. Avoid to learn Microsoft methods. Try to learn standard computation...

Comment: it looks like you have "hours" in your dateString variable, but there is no "hours" variable, should it be "hour"?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that ActiveX controls are being phased out and are no longer supported in the most recent IE versions unless you use compatibility mode. And the newest browser Edge which replaces IE in Windows 10 doesn't even have that -- ActiveX is firmly in the past. Your code is already obsolete, and will break when your users upgrade. You would be well advised to start planning for that now.

Comment: @Spudley The logging is simply for me and no one else, however, is there a newer way to write to a file in a similar way that I'm doing?

Comment: Yep: There is the [File API](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/file) which allows you to read and write to the local file system (within certain security constraints). This is supported by all the major current browser releases. Alternatively, you could keep the log data within the browser using the [LocalStorage API](http://html5tutorial.net/tutorials/working-with-html5-localstorage.html); this doesn't create a separate file and is only accessible from within the site that created it and in the same browser, but it is persistent and doesn't get deleted when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
var dateString = "" + day "/" + m

var dateString = "" + day + "/" + m
```

Missing + on the string concat. minutes is missing a + sign as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your additional code has a syntax error, which is causing the whole of Logging.js not to compile, and thus not to get run.

The best way to avoid this kind of thing happening in the future is to always run your code through a syntax checker or lint checker before deploying it.

For example, [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) would have picked up this error immediately. Good practice is to set up a "build" process, which runs these kinds of checks automatically every time you update your code. This concept is called "Continuous integration" and is a key factor in making your code robust and avoiding embarrassing errors getting deployed to live systems.